# When do i need to load notifications data from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to show some sign inside my app that there are unread messages. I am doing background requests to server to be sure there is new content to show.

I am not sure - how often should I check server for updates. I thought that it would be nice to check for updates in viewDidLoad method of my ViewController. But app can go to background and after coming back after few days - viewDidLoad won't be triggered. Otherwise if I put it inside viewWillAppear - it should be used more often than it should be.

How it should be done?

Comment: You can use `applicationWillEnterForeground` method of AppDelegate to ask your server for an update when app is returned from background

Comment: That's not notifications, that's polling, no? Can't you use APNS?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use silent push notifications to trigger sync. When a silent push notification reaches device, user does not know anything about the notification. But your app gets the notification and app will be given some time to download new content and present it to the user. You can read more about it here - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html , in Configuring a Silent Notification section

Comment: Thank you, Olga. What will happen if user won't agree to use push-notification for my app?

Comment: The push notifications will not arrive, of course. You can convince user to enable them by explaining why do you need this permission and what the user will lose in case of denial. If the user will not agree, you can, for example, update your content once a day (or more often, depends on your needs) - just store the timestamp of last update and compare it with current date in viewWillAppear.